# Tkinter button state overwrites

Tags: python, button, tkinter, state

I am trying to make tic tac toe using tkinter, I am storing player and computer inputs in lists and use them to check if the input place is already taken or not. However, it is not working and after the second turn, disabled-buttons turn to normal, although they are already marked. So can someone please point out which part of code return the button to normal state.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
root.geometry("400x400")
global playerletter
global computerletter
playerletter = "X"
computerletter = "O"
x = 50
y = 50
playerList = []
computerList = []

def turn(button, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6, box7, box8, box9):
    global count
    count = 0
    playerList.insert(count, button)
    if (button == 1):
        box1 = Button(root, text=playerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    if (button == 2):
        box2 = Button(root, text=playerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    if (button == 3):
        box3 = Button(root, text=playerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box3.grid(row=1, column=2)
    if (button == 4):
        box4 = Button(root, text=playerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box4.grid(row=2, column=0)
    if (button == 5):
        box5 = Button(root, text=playerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box5.grid(row=2, column=1)
    if (button == 6):
        box6 = Button(root, text=playerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box6.grid(row=2, column=2)
    if (button == 7):
        box7 = Button(root, text=playerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box7.grid(row=3, column=0)
    if (button == 8):
        box8 = Button(root, text=playerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box8.grid(row=3, column=1)        
    if (button == 9):
        box9 = Button(root, text=playerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box9.grid(row=3, column=2)

    computer_input = random.randint(1, 9)

    computerList.insert(count, Button)

    for butts in playerList:
        if (computer_input == butts):
            while (computer_input==butts):
                computer_input = random.randint(1, 9)
                computerList.pop(count)
                computerList.insert(count, Button)                

    for cuts in computerList:
        if (computer_input == cuts):
            while (computer_input==cuts):
                computer_input = random.randint(1, 9)
                computerList.pop(count)
                computerList.insert(count, Button)

    count += 1

    if (computer_input == 1 and box1['state'] != "DISABLED"):
        box1 = Button(root, text=computerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    if (computer_input == 2 and box2['state'] != "DISABLED"):
        box2 = Button(root, text=computerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    if (computer_input == 3 and box3['state'] != "DISABLED" ):
        box3 = Button(root, text=computerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box3.grid(row=1, column=2)

    if (computer_input == 4 and box4['state'] != "DISABLED" ):
        box4 = Button(root, text=computerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box4.grid(row=2, column=0)

    if (computer_input == 5 and box5['state'] != "DISABLED"):
        box5 = Button(root, text=computerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box5.grid(row=2, column=1)

    if (computer_input == 6 and box6['state'] != "DISABLED"):
        box6 = Button(root, text=computerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box6.grid(row=2, column=2)

    if (computer_input == 7 and box7['state'] != "DISABLED" ):
        box7 = Button(root, text=computerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box7.grid(row=3, column=0)

    if (computer_input == 8 and box8['state'] != "DISABLED" ):
        box8 = Button(root, text=computerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box8.grid(row=3, column=1)    

    if (computer_input == 9 and box9['state'] != "DISABLED"):
        box9 = Button(root, text=computerletter, state=DISABLED, padx=x, pady=y)
        box9.grid(row=3, column=2)      

    print("PLAYER CHOSE: ", button)
    print("COMPUTER CHOSE: ", computer_input)
    
    print("BOX 1 IS ", box1['state'])
box1 = Button(root, text="", padx=x, pady=y, command= lambda: turn(1, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, 
box6, box7, box8, box9))
box1.grid(row=1, column=0)
box2 = Button(root, text="", padx=x, pady=y, command=lambda: turn(2, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, 
box6, 
box7, box8, box9))
box2.grid(row=1, column=1)
box3 = Button(root, text="", padx=x, pady=y, command=lambda: turn(3, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, 
box6, 
box7, box8, box9))
box3.grid(row=1, column=2)
box4 = Button(root, text="", padx=x, pady=y, command=lambda: turn(4, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, 
box6, box7, box8, box9))
box4.grid(row=2, column=0)
box5 = Button(root, text="", padx=x, pady=y, command=lambda: turn(5, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, 
box6, box7, box8, box9))
box5.grid(row=2, column=1)
box6 = Button(root, text="", padx=x, pady=y, command=lambda: turn(6, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, 
box6, box7, box8, box9))
box6.grid(row=2, column=2)
box7 = Button(root, text="", padx=x, pady=y, command=lambda: turn(7, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, 
box6, box7, box8, box9))
box7.grid(row=3, column=0)
box8 = Button(root, text="", padx=x, pady=y, command=lambda: turn(8, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, 
box6, box7, box8, box9))
box8.grid(row=3, column=1)
box9 = Button(root, text="", padx=x, pady=y, command=lambda: turn(9, box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, 
box6, box7, box8, box9))
box9.grid(row=3, column=2)
mainloop()
```

Comment: *after the second turn, disabled-buttons turn to normal.* I couldn't reproduce that.

Comment: eg I mark button 1, it will be disabled. But when I mark another button, button 1 becomes normal

Comment: Yes, I couldn't reproduce that issue.

Comment: can you try running it 2 3 times, you will probably notice that "O" overwrites "X" buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a little complex. this is the cause of your issue:

```
    computer_input = random.randint(1, 9)

    computerList.insert(count, computer_input)

    for butts in playerList:
        if (computer_input == butts):
            while (computer_input==butts):
                computer_input = random.randint(1, 9)
                computerList.pop(count)
                computerList.insert(count, Button)                

    for cuts in computerList:
        if (computer_input == cuts):
            while (computer_input==cuts):
                computer_input = random.randint(1, 9)
                computerList.pop(count)
                computerList.insert(count, Button)

    count += 1
```

---

I know what you want, but the direct way is to use `set`.
Simplify this logic, this will generate a number that didn't belong to player and computer previous selection:

```
    if len(computerList) != 4: # computer could only take less than four steps
        computer_input = random.choice(list(set(range(1, 10))-set(playerList)-set(computerList))) # use set to calculate the result

        computerList.append(computer_input)
```